# Magento need cron job? if i remove cron

Tags: magento2, cron

I have a question.

Magento need cron job? if i remove cron can it work normally?

Because cron make our site so slowly. we already setting 1 hour delete from cron_schedule.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can run Magento without cron. No critical problem will be there. If you need, you may run **cron** and **reindex** manually whenever its required.

Comment: Hi,but i getting message in backend need to install cron job. if not install cron job, i in Index Management is choose "update on save"? @manishjoy

Comment: please share the screenshot @niceonelee